# Emacs: How to switch mode after typing certain string?

Tags: emacs, latex, elisp, markdown

I am writing R Markdown (.Rmd) file with a lot of LaTeX contents. The major mode is Markdown-mode. But what I want is that: when I try to type some LaTeX commands between `$$`, I want to automatically turn on the LaTeX major mode, and after I end the LaTeX chunk with `$$` or `$`, it can turn off LaTeX major mode and turn on Markdown-mode again.

The inline format for LaTeX is

```
$\alpha$
```

The equation(displaymath) format for LaTeX is

```
$$
\alpha + \beta
$$
```

A similar example is when I was writing a `.Rnw` file, the major mode is LaTeX, but when I edit the R
code chunk:

```
<<>>=
y <- 1000
@
```

between `<<>>=` and `@`, it turns on the ESS mode.

So can anyone help me to do the similar stuff in Markdown-LaTeX case? Thanks!

---

Updates after Inaimathi's answer:

Following http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes#toc6, I need to modify the two-mode-mode.el

```
- (if (string= to-mode mode-name)
+ (if (string= to-mode major-mode)
```

and for emacs 24

```
- (make-local-hook 'post-command-hook)
```

Then, by Inaimathi, I put the following in my `.emacs`:

```
(require 'two-mode-mode)
(setq default-mode (list "Markdown" 'markdown-mode)
      second-modes (list (list "LaTeX" "\\\[" "\\\]" 'latex-mode)))
```

Then the major mode switches between `\[` and `\]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ok with your major mode changing as you navigate, [`two-mode-mode`](http://www.welton.it/freesoftware/files/two-mode-mode.el) should be able to do what you need. You need to include that `.el`, then add a block that looks something like

```
(require 'two-mode-mode)
(setq default-mode (list "Haskell" 'haskell-mode)
      second-modes (list (list "Markdown" "\[markdown|" "|\]" 'markdown-mode)))
```

to your `~/.emacs`. The above is what I do to highlight `markdown` blocks while editing [Elm](http://elm-lang.org/) code. For your particular use case, you'd probably need

```
(require 'two-mode-mode)
(setq default-mode (list "Markdown" 'markdown-mode)
      second-modes (list (list "Latex" "\$\$" "\$\$" 'latex-mode)
                         (list "Latex" "<<>>=" "@" 'latex-mode)))
```

Instead. This is completely untested, includes no warranty, etc etc.

Ideally, what I'd like in that situation is for the rest of the buffer to keep `markdown-mode` highlighting, and have just the particular region get highlighted in `latex-mode` or whatever. Near as I can tell, there isn't a ready, general solution for that, but if you're up for some Elisp hacking, you could give [this](http://www.loveshack.ukfsn.org/emacs/haskell-latex.el) a read and see what you can come up with.